# Git bash on Windows different result than terminal on CentOS for regex

Tags: bash, git-bash, glob

See the following `cleanCustomer.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
customer=Reportçós
cleanedCustomer=${customer//[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_.]/}
echo $cleanedCustomer
```

When I run it on Windows 11 in Git Bash it prints `Reports`.
When I run it on CentOS in terminal it prints `Reportçós`.

Anybody knows why is `a-z` interpreted as alpha characters in CentOS and not in Windows?
How do I ensure only english characters are considered in the CentOS?

Comment: Looks like collations. Try `LC_ALL=C cleanedCustomer=${customer//[^a-zA-Z0-9 _.-]/}`. I guess `\-` was used to escape `-`. Also, it is not a regex, it is a glob pattern.

Comment: thanks. Took me some time to find documentation that is a glob and not regex: [see ${parameter/pattern/string}](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

> A pair of characters separated by a hyphen denotes a range expression; any character that falls between those two characters, inclusive, using the current locale’s collating sequence and character set, is matched. If the first character following the ‘[’ is a ‘!’ or a ‘^’ then any character not enclosed is matched. A ‘-’ may be matched by including it as the first or last character in the set.

Your Git Bash locale uses rules that don't match accented characters in ranges like `a-z`, your CentOS locale does. This can be addressed by using a consistent locale like `C` for collation. Plus your `-` is in the wrong spot; it needs to be first or last, and the backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash to match a literal one.

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_COLLATE=C
customer=Reportçós
cleanedCustomer=${customer//[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\_.-]/}
printf "%s\n" "$cleanedCustomer"
```

Comment: thanks. Although I'll make a correction to your correction since you dropped "\" (it is a literal, not an escape character).  
You are correct that the `-` needs to go to the end (or start) to be matched.  
`cleanedCustomer=${customer//[^a-zA-Z0-9 \_.-]/}`  
The following characters (excluding alphanumerics) are meant to be "cleaned": ` ` (space), "\", `_`, `.`, `-`. But this is kinda out of scope of the question.  
The `LC_COLLATE` does the job/is the answer.

Comment: @Krakowskimudrac You were trying to match a literal backslash? That *will* have to be escaped in the pattern - two backslashes, not one.

Comment: not correct @Shawn - i just tested. Only 1 backslash is fine for literal match.

Comment: Wasn't working for me but I might have messed up somewhere. (Tried again, and I need the doubled backslash to avoid stripping them from a string. bash 4.4.20).

Comment: you are right! I had messed something up! So this is the regex I need:  
`${customer//[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\_.-]/}`